# Forbid external lib's class methods to access network in Java 8

Tags: java, classloader

I have application which uses external library for parsing some files and I want to prevent external lib's classes from sending any http requests. Can it be achieved without using SecurityManager?

I tried making a custom ClassLoader but I can't find a way to use the same custom ClassLoader for every class that is instantiated in a method that can make a http request.

Comment: What's wrong with a security manager?

Comment: @g00se Sooner or later I will upgrade JDK version and since SecirutyManager is deprecated for removal I'm afraid that SecurityManager is a temporary solution for a problem.

Comment: The reason `SecurityManager` is deprecated is that it turned out that running untrusted code and pretending it's secure is a risky proposition: there's too many ways to circumvent the security manager to make it truly secure. You'd need to trust your third-party code anyway. So your third-party code should have an option to not use networking and you should use that. And if you don't have that amount of trust for your third-party code, then you almost certainly shouldn't let it run in the same process as your code anyway and need stronger encapsulation (maybe even inside an isolated container)